# How to make this bot listen to argument after prefix and answer?

Tags: discord, discord.js

so i'm trying this 8ball bot, and everything is working fine, but i can't get how can i leave in the condition that only when the bot get "!verda arg1 arg2" it answers one of the replies in the array.

meanwhile my condition is if the user type the prefix "!verda" only, it replies , i want to include the argument too in the condition

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const cfg = require("./config.json");

const prefix = cfg.prefix;

client.on("message", msg => {
    if (!msg.content.startsWith(prefix) || msg.author.bot) return;

    const args = msg.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase;

    if (msg.content === prefix){
        let replies = [
            "Yes.",
            "No.",
            "I don't know.",
            "Maybe."
        ];
        let result = Math.floor((Math.random() * replies.length));
        msg.channel.send(replies[result]);
    }


    else if (msg.content === "!help"){
        msg.channel.send("I have only 1 command [!verda]");
    }


})

client.login(cfg.token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase;
```

`toLowerCase` is a function and therefore should be

```
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
```

By doing `msg.content === prefix`, you are checking if the whole content of the message is equal to that of `cfg.prefix`

```
if(msg.content.startsWith(`${prefix}8ball`) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple as i figured it out, i simply had to join the spaces

```
if (msg.content === `${prefix} ${args.join(" ")}`)
```